# How to custom validation with input value as name already been taken?

Tags: laravel, laravel-7, laravel-6.2

In controller

```
public function store(Request $req)
{
    $req->validate([
    'username' => 'required|unique:users',
    ]);

    $users = new Users();
    $users->username = $req->username;
    $users->save();        
    return redirect()->route('list.users');
}
```

The username validation return as `The username has already been taken.`

I am typing the username field as JHON and i would to return the validation as like: `The JHON has already been taken.` ?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can use `:input` when defining custom validation messages.

```
public function store(Request $req)
{
    Validator::make($req, [
        'username' => 'required|unique:users',
    ], [
        'unique' => 'The :input username has already been taken.',
    ]);

    $users = new Users();
    $users->username = $req->username;
    $users->save();        
    return redirect()->route('list.users');
}
```

Comment: Thank you dear for quick support.

Answer (score 1):

To make your code cleaner, you should change the localization of the "unique" validation error

Go to the file "resources/lang/en/validation.php" (or change the "en" part with your language's iso code) and change the "unique" value.

From:

```
'unique' => 'The :attribute has already been taken.',
```

To:

```
'unique' => 'The :attribute :input has already been taken.',
```

This way, you should get the following message

> The username JHON has already been taken.

Comment: Good answer. how do like this? The :placeholder :input has already been taken. because my attribute name="name" and my placeholder="User Name", so would like The username JHON has already been taken.

Comment: In that case the easiest solution would be to rename "name" to "username". The placeholder is not sent to php.

Answer (score 0):

```
$req->validate([
    'username' => 'required|unique:users,username',
    ]);
```

This is the syntax for using unique:

`unique:table,column`

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/validation#rule-unique

Comment: I believe that the OP's question was how to modify the error message with the user's input in the message. In this case the username that the user typed in. You can use the unique validation rule without specifying the column if the column name is equal to the attribute that is being validated.